# Multiple lights without compounding brightness

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Directional Lights on my 2.5D scene.  I have multiple spotlights going across the level, but when they overlap the brightness is ugly.

Is there any way to maintain the same brightness on a material regardless if there is 1 light shining on it or 2?

Comment: Have you checked the **Pixel Light Count**? I'm not sure what "ugly" would be in this case, but I had the issues with jagged lights intersecting and increasing this count while having more lights in the scene solved my problems.  You can find it at _Edit > Preferences > Quality_.

Comment: Yeah the count is pretty high, by ugly I just mean way too bright.  I want the brightness to stay the same regardless if there's 1 light on an area or 20

Comment: I'm not very aware about how shaders work, but I guess the Unity editor wouldn't give you that result. My guess would be modifying or tweaking the shader of the material contained in the object. Can't help with that, but maybe that could give you a lead. :/

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are using gamma colorspace instead of linear. Try to go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Player -> Other Settings and change the colorspace mode.

At first it might destroy the entire ilumination of the scene but if you tweek the lights, in the end, you'll have much better results.